# High Current Many-Channel DAC

Tags: dac

I've been looking at DACs on Digikey and other electronics sites in hopes of finding a circuit to drive > 20 electrical nodes with ~10 mA per channel, 0->8V, with ~16-bit precision. I've seen evaluation boards from Analog Devices that offer 40 channels with the specifications, but they can only handle 1 mA load current. Does anyone have any suggestions for pre-made systems that could handle this sort of situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DACs typically don't sink or source much current; typically to drive the output harder you use an op-amp which can drive to your requirements on the output of the DAC. If you need even more current than that, you can use a pass transistor or FET on the op-amp output and close the loop around it.

TI has a [three](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt342/slyt342.pdf) [part](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt360/slyt360.pdf) [series](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt368/slyt368.pdf) on interfacing op-amps to DACs which probably goes into a lot more detail than you're after, but which I'm providing here for others interested in it.

[Op-Amps for Everyone](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781856175050) has an [entire chapter](http://bit.ly/1fSq9qX) (both safari online links) on interfacing DACs to loads which you might find enlightening, in particular "Current Boosters" in 18.7.1.

[This psocdeveloper forum post](http://www.psocdeveloper.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=6359) goes into more detail about using a FET in the output path of a voltage-following op-amp which is connected to the output of a DAC in order to boost the current capability of the DAC. As I mentioned though, practically any op-amp can give you 10mA sink/source capability so you probably do not need to go this far.

A quick Digikey search shows op-amps like the MAX4495, AD8625 and HT1104 can supply 15mA per channel. You might want to take a look there and see where it leads you.

Comment: I'm hoping to do this without generating a new PCB. http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv1059=13&pv153=5&FV=fff40028%2Cfff8044c&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

Comment: ^^a DAC that can supply 1mA/channel with 40 channels. Is there any "buffer board" that can amplify the current for many channels that you've heard of?

Comment: If you're trying to replace an existing DAC device, could you generate a piggy-back PCB that drops onto the existing one in place of the DAC chip but includes the buffers? I think you're on a long-shot finding a DAC with the capabilities you're after that will drop-in in place of whatever you're already using, pin-for-pin.

Comment: @nick_name I don't know of anything off the shelf like that, no.